# Multiple Select in MaterializeCSS?

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

Is there a way to use Multiple Select with Materialize CSS ? Or other stylized component that does the same?

Something like tagging stack overflow style

```
tag (x), tag (x)
```

Did you understand?

Comment: This may be relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207047/how-to-get-mutiselect-dropdown-in-materialize-css/30515050#30515050

Comment: Maybe, but I would like a stylized option! :D thx!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Chips component now (v0.97.1).
http://materializecss.com/chips.html

Comment: Thats exactly I want!  thks!