# How to get multi select dropdown in Materialize css?

Tags: css, materialize

I am working on a project which uses Materialize css for front end.

Is there any way to get multi select option for dropdown in Materialize css ?

Any piece of info would be helpful.

Answer (score 13):

You only have to add the `multiple`:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select multiple>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
</div>
```

And then call js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ak0on6kL/124/)

Answer (score -1):

MaterializeCSS's dropdown implementation is not a `<select>` block. It is just a styled `<ul>`. Therefore, I don't believe you can take advantage of a multi-select with their implementation. I would use the default `<select>` block like this:

```
<select class="browser-default" multiple>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Note: you must add the `browser-default` class so that MaterializeCSS doesn't render it.

Answer (score -2):

Since the top and left css properties of the label are set to ~0.8rem each, you can add a specific rule to the li's:

```css
#topics_dropdown li {
  height: 3rem;
}
```